# How to transfer table in SQL Server 2008 from one computer to another

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to transfer my table in SQL Server 2008 from one computer to another... Is it possible?

How to transfer from one computer to another? I am doing my final year project. In my project, if the table contains more number of rows means it will divide the table into smaller partition and transfer that partition to another computer.. is it possible to transfer?

Comment: i want to send my table to another computer..now that computer perform some operation then it will return the result to previous computer..how to do this???

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways, you could:

1) Dettach the database and copy the database files (mdf and ldf) over to the other computer then attach it.

2) Backup the database to a .bak file, copy that over and restore on the other computer.

3) Use the Import Export wizard to move just the table into a new database on the other computer.

4) If you need to do this regularly then maybe you could write an SSIS package to do it.

The easiest way is option 1.

Comment: @richard..i want to communicate with two computer...if the table contain more number of rows means it will partition into sub partition...now that sub partition is transferred to another computer...now that computer performs some operation and return their result to main computer

Comment: It sounds like you are not just wanting to do a simple database transfer, sounds like you are moving data backwards and forwards.  In that case use option 4 and write an SSIS package.